Variable product attribute description for global attribute
I am importing products via a csv and I'm able to import variable products. My variations are "Outright" and "Exchange" (outright is you buy the product, exchange is you buy the product and send us back your old part). Woocom let's me add a "description" to my "attribute" which is great.
My question is, is there a way I can add my description attribute to every product that has "outright" and "exchange"? Ideally, I'd do this in the csv but I don't see an attribute description field. We have 1000+ products so adding a description to each product is too much so I'd like to try and automate this. Any ideas? Cheers!





Figured it out a few minutes after posting. in the "description" column of your cvs add the variations description there. brain fart
